# How do we know whether call to epoll_wait() is edge triggered or level triggered?

Tags: linux, epoll

I know that specifying the event `EPOLLET`switches epoll from being level-triggered to edge-triggered.
Does it mean by default call to `epoll_wait()` is Level-Triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html

```
By contrast, when used as a level-triggered interface (the default,
when EPOLLET is not specified), epoll is simply a faster poll(2), and
can be used wherever the latter is used since it shares the same
semantics.
```

So, when EPOLLET is not specified, level-triggered is the default option.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread. I came here looking to see how I can know if `epoll_wait` is for a file descriptor in EPOLLET mode. Going through the codebase is one solution, but I found a workaround using [bpftrace](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace) and then inspecting the `/proc` file.

Steps (i) get the process id and file descriptors for epoll `bpftrace -e 't:syscalls:sys_enter_epoll_wait { @pid[comm, pid, args->epfd] = count(); }'` and then (ii) check if flag EPOLLET set on the file descriptor `cat /proc/[pid]/fdinfo/[epfd]`

For details on the `/proc` file see [link](https://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman5/proc.5.html), in this cases you will be interested in the flags attribute.